# (php) Should we use a grabage collector for Redis based session handling?

Tags: php, redis

I have set to use REDIS as my PHP session handler.
There seems to be a session expiration issue when used with REDIS. Am I correct? Or ttl lifetime of each redis key itself handles the expiration of sessions?

What I use, is simply setting the handler to use REDIS. Also it seems PHP does not take care of garbage collection if the session handler gets changed.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, there is no need for session garbage collection when using Redis. Each key has its own TTL that you can check using the `TTL` command. In my dev environment I have the session handler set to redis, and then access my test site. When I run `KEYS *`, I get the key for my session. I then run `TLL "PHPREDIS_SESSION:<session key>` and I get the time remaining before the session is collected.

You can test it yourself using a very short gc_maxlifetime value. eg 15.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "PHPREDIS_SESSION:otgaqapormlo7l0pjpl6v7upq1"
127.0.0.1:6379> TTL "PHPREDIS_SESSION:otgaqapormlo7l0pjpl6v7upq1"
(integer) 6
127.0.0.1:6379> TTL "PHPREDIS_SESSION:otgaqapormlo7l0pjpl6v7upq1"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> TTL "PHPREDIS_SESSION:otgaqapormlo7l0pjpl6v7upq1"
(integer) -2
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
(empty list or set)
```

Comment: can confirm: using php.ini `session.save_handler=rediscluster`  and `session_gc();` returns false in 5 microseconds (0.000005 seconds), way too fast to do anything, it's clear that session_gc() does *nothing* with session.save_handler=rediscluster :)